# How to create an array of items and fetch them with .all()?

Tags: craft3, forloop

Is there a way to create an array of items, fetch them with .all() and loop through them?  For example:

```
{% set array = array|merge([block]) %}

{% for block in gallery.all() %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `.all()` lives in the element query classes, not on an array.  If you've already got your results in array format, why not just loop through them directly?

Comment: I was just curious to know if there is a way to do so, but looping through as an array is fine.